# how to filter *ngFor result based on a selected dropdown value

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, ngfor

Choosing a category:

```
 <ion-select name="categories">
    <ion-option *ngFor="let category of categories;">
      {{category}}
    </ion-option>
  </ion-select>
```

Listing the items:

```
 <ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let item of items; let idx = index;">
    <ion-item>
        <h2>{{item.title}}</h2>
    </ion-item>
...
</ion-item-sliding>
```

How can I use the value from  (select) to choose which category gets listed? I tried adding a ngModule in  and passing it as a condition into the sliding ngFor, but it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a pipe to achieve this

```
 <ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let item of items | categorySelected; let idx = index;">
    <ion-item>
        <h2>{{item.title}}</h2>
    </ion-item>
...
</ion-item-sliding>
```

In your transform method you can perform your logic

```
transform(s[],cat){
    ///logic

return filteredArray
}
```

[**Sample Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/4e5aPGjdd9qsDu2XbXqz?p=info)

Update 1 : Complete answer

Custom pipe will have the below code,

```
transform(records: Array<any>, property:any): any {
      let sortedArray=[];
      if(property){
      sortedArray =_.filter(records, {'office':property.Name]);
      console.log(sortedArray);
      return sortedArray
      }
  }
```

Dropdown and list of items

```
<div>
  <select [(ngModel)]="selectedElement">
    <option *ngFor="let type of types" [ngValue]="type">
      {{type.Name}}</option>
  </select>
  <span *ngFor="let x of array | orderBy:selectedElement">{{x.firstName}}</span>
</div>
```

**[LIVE DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/4e5aPGjdd9qsDu2XbXqz?p=preview)**

Comment: You are correct, `pipe` is the right way to go here. But perhaps a more solid example would help the dude a bit more. [Pipes in Angular.io docs](https://angular.io/guide/pipes)

Comment: shouldn't the pipe receive a parameter? this answer isn't complete

Comment: I might have sent input to the pipe.

Comment: @Jota.Toledo check the updated answer. also see the demo.

Comment: sortedArray =_.filter(records, {'office':property.Name]); The underscore isn't defined.

Comment: You might have got error. Check the loadsh script reference

Comment: @Aravind I cannot import Lodash using Ionic (ng4).

Answer (score 2):

you can use [ngx-pipes](https://github.com/danrevah/ngx-pipes) library for doing incredible filtering and transforming in arrays and strings.

for your Question you can use filterBy pipe in `ngx-pipes` library.

```
<ion-option *ngFor="let category of categories | filterBy:['name']:selectedVariable;">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also simply put

```
    ngOnChanges() {
       this.itemsForDisplay = this.items.filter(element => element.category = this.category);
    }
```

and display `itemsForDisplay` in your template instead of `items`