# How to implement custom filter for each specify column in data table using angular4?

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular-datatables

Following github package for very nicely implemented data table, This data table contain sort, filter(But not column wise)

https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-datatable

http://plnkr.co/edit/PxBaZs?p=preview

but here column wise filter is not implemented like column wise sort,

```
<tr>
<th style="width: 10%"></th>
<th style="width: 20%">
    <mfDefaultSorter by="name">Name</mfDefaultSorter>
</th>
<th style="width: 40%">
    <mfDefaultSorter by="email">Email</mfDefaultSorter>
</th>
<th style="width: 10%">
    <mfDefaultSorter by="age">Age</mfDefaultSorter>
</th>
<th style="width: 20%">
    City
</th>
```

```
export class DefaultSorter implements OnInit {
@Input("by") sortBy: string;

isSortedByMeAsc: boolean = false;
isSortedByMeDesc: boolean = false;

public constructor(private mfTable: DataTable) {
}

public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.mfTable.onSortChange.subscribe((event: SortEvent) => {
        this.isSortedByMeAsc = (event.sortBy == this.sortBy && event.sortOrder == "asc");
        this.isSortedByMeDesc = (event.sortBy == this.sortBy && event.sortOrder == "desc");
    });
}

sort() {
    if (this.isSortedByMeAsc) {
        this.mfTable.setSort(this.sortBy, "desc");
    } else {
        this.mfTable.setSort(this.sortBy, "asc");
    }
}}
```

Like this I want implement custom filter for specifying row

If any one can help me to customize the code and to implement custom filter for specifying columns, or please give me suggitions, I want to implement my own filter.

Thanks in advace

Comment: Refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45267001/how-to-filter-ngfor-result-based-on-a-selected-dropdown-value)

Comment: this is not related what I am looking for