# How to order object by value Angular 2?

Tags: angular

I have `ul` list:

```
<ul>
<li [ngClass]="{'active': lang.def, 'show': opened}" *ngFor="let lang of languages | orderBy: 'def': 1">{{lang.name}</li>
</ul>
```

I tried to sort object `languages` by value `def`. So, first should be `li` elements with `def` = 1

I tried this `pipe` filter:

```
export class OrderBy {

  transform(array: any, orderBy: any, asc = true) {
    array.sort(function(x: any, y: any) {
      return (x.def > y.def) ? x.def : y.def;
    });

    return array;
  }
}
```

But it does not work for me.

Json Object:

```
[ { "id": 2, "code": "ru", "active": true, "def": 0, "hide": false }, { "id": 1, "code": "az", "active": true, "def": 1, "hide": false } ]
```

Comment: can you explain using a sample json data?? Also, refer [**this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45267001/how-to-filter-ngfor-result-based-on-a-selected-dropdown-value/45267033#45267033)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to post JSON object, see again

Comment: I need that element with `def = 1` will be firstly

Comment: You should read up on what the sort method actually does, how `compareFunction` is used, rather than guessing: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is a mistake in your sort function. Here is the solution

```
export class OrderBy implements PipeTransform {
     transform(array: any, orderBy: any, asc = true) {
       array.sort((x, y) => x.def - y.def);

    return array;
  }
}
```